# File cannot be deleted and renamed

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I have the following scenario:

1. The program can find the file and can read the first line (-120) (from arenas_be1.txt)
2. The program can add 1 to -120 and write it into f1.txt
3. Nothing happens then, the method will be called one second later with the same numbers (-120) and (-120+1)

I think that the problem is that the main-file cant be deleted, but why?

```
public void defaultGameStart() {

    this.getServer().getScheduler()
            .scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setCountdownLess();
                }
            }, 20, 20);
}

public void setCountdownLess() {
    File zuÄnderndeDatei = new File("plugins/DB/join_signs.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                zuÄnderndeDatei));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] spLine = line.split(";");
            if (spLine[2].startsWith("BE")) {
                File zuÄnderndeDatei11 = new File("plugins/DB/arenas/arenas_"+spLine[2].toLowerCase()+".txt");
                File buffer = new File("plugins/DB/arenas/f1.txt");
                try {

                    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            zuÄnderndeDatei11));
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(buffer));
                    String line1;
                    System.out.println("-> "+spLine[2]);

                    line1 = reader1.readLine();
                    System.out.println("-> "+line1);
                    writer.write((Integer.parseInt(line1) + 1)+"");
                    writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    countDownToStart((Integer.parseInt(line1) + 1),
                            spLine[2]);

                    System.out.println("-> "+(Integer.parseInt(line1) + 1));
                    reader1.close();
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();

                    zuÄnderndeDatei11.setWritable(true);
                    if (zuÄnderndeDatei11.delete()) {
                        buffer.renameTo(zuÄnderndeDatei11);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Fehler beim Anpassen der Template-Datei<>setcountdownless");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By the way, this is a Bukkit plugin.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it but I think you can't delete it because it's being used by reader and you close it after the attempt to delete it.

Comment: Try to get rid of the umlauts first..

Comment: Double check your file pemissions, never hurts...

Comment: just an FYI, you don't need to call writer.flush(); AND writer.close(); Flush does what close does WITHOUT releasing the buffer and making it unusable. So depending on your goal, call one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (zuÄnderndeDatei11.delete()) {
                    buffer.renameTo(zuÄnderndeDatei11);
                }
```

is returning `false`

because you didn't close the reader before trying to delete. if the reader is not closed before you try to delete the file, the system will not delete it because it thinks that the user still has the file open(which you do, but through java). you need to close the reader and then try to delete it.

**EDIT:** and also why are you creating a countdown through a file? this is so inefficient it is going to make me cry. use this:

```
final int time = 90;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       if(time > 0)
          time--;
       else
       {
          timer.cancel();
          //do something
       }
    }
},1000,1000);
```